# NFC Nexus S, make readOnly Tag error

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, iso-15693

I try to make a NFC-V, NDEF tag to be readOnly. But it doesn't work.
I tried the `formatReadOnly(...)` method, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to test if the tag can be made read only with the method: `canMakeReadOnly()`.
The answer is **false**.

So how can I protect my tags?
Does the problem come from the Nexus or from the tag itself?

Any ideas?

Comment: What's NFC-V and NDEF? How is it releated to D? Show body of these functions.